# Mega Manager for Mac OS X (MegaUpload)

Tags: macos, upload, download-manager

There are many download manager and/or accelerator that work with MegaUpload under OS X, but I 'm searching for an OS X alternative to [Mega Manager](http://www.megaupload.com/?c=tools): it manages multiple **upload** and download to/from Mega Upload.

Do you know one?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't live without [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/download/index); it will watch RapidShare & MegaUpload (and others) for the countdown timer, provide some nice speedups and tons more. Oh, and it's written in Java, so it runs on OS X, Windows & Linux (& Solaris I guess) :)

Comment: Can I use JDownloader as an upload manager for Mega Upload?

Comment: @dag no, see [here](http://board.jdownloader.org/showthread.php?t=488); *"we are a downloader. no super ultra swiss army knife."*

Comment: Unfortunately JDownloader will not be useful to my purpose...ok, I don't want a super ultra army knife, but what about an upload manager? :D Thanks for your informations TPP.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer [Speed Download](http://www.yazsoft.com/products/speed-download/) myself, but it doesn't appear as though they have MegaUpload support (at least upload).

Comment: It seems a great software but, as you can see, there isn't an upload feature. Thanks anyway Josh!

Answer (score 0):

Finally found a software that correspond to the aforementioned requirements: its name is MegaSquirrel and you'll find it here

http://www.psp-cheats.it/redsquirrel/MegaSquirrel.html

EDIT: It is for linux, not for OSX.